# Adjusting column/row width/height based on the number of them

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel, column-width

I have a `tableLayoutPanel` with two rows and two columns called `GameGrid`.

When `button1` is pressed I want:

A column and a row to be added,

All the columns to be adjusted to equal widths,

All the rows to be adjusted to equal heights.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
//Add a new row and row style
GameGrid.RowCount++;
GameGrid.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 10));

//change all the rowstyles to the entire width / the number of rows
foreach (RowStyle style in this.GameGrid.RowStyles)
{
    style.SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
    style.Height = GameGrid.Width / GameGrid.RowCount;
}

//do the same for the columns
GameGrid.ColumnCount++;
GameGrid.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 10));
foreach (ColumnStyle style in this.GameGrid.ColumnStyles)
{
    style.SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
    style.Width = GameGrid.Height / GameGrid.ColumnCount;
}
```

But this doesn't quite work and I end up with this:
[image: Code Result]

Why is the last column/row longer than the rest, and what would work instead?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what the values are of `style.Height` and `style.Width` before/after change, `GameGrid.Width`, `GameGrid.Height`, `GameGrid.RowCount`, and `GameGrid.ColumnCount`?

Comment: @JohnOdom errr, sorry, i'm still new to visual studio/C#. How would I do that?

Comment: You would add breakpoints on the line that you want to stop the program at (I would do it on `GameGrid.RowCount++;`). Then you would press F5 to begin debugging and then you would press F10 to step through the code line-by-line. Read up on how to debug C# applications to learn more :) Debugging is crucial in developing efficient applications.

Comment: @JohnOdom ok, will do!

Comment: Good to hear! Be sure to come back and add to the question if you still need help or add an answer on what the solution was.

Comment: This is a normal TableLayoutPanel control behaviour - the last row gets always the whole left space to fill the control width/height. As a start, set the style to absolute (`style.SizeType = SizeType.Absolute`) for both rows and columns and set the Width and Height property of your TableLayoutControl to the same value! This would not solve the problem entirely, but would make the TableLayoutPanel control somewhat better looking.

Comment: @JohnOdom they all show correct values. Why dont they look it? Is there something wrong with my maths rather than wrong with my code?

Comment: @pasty that changes things, but doesn't fix it by any means, why don't the numbers add up then?